# Explicit GC getting called while video playback leading to frame drops of nearly more than 10%

Tags: android, video, garbage-collection

I am running a video playback which only has video in it without any audio content in it. We are using OMXCodec and Awesomeplayer combination for the playback.

What i observe in the systrace and log file is that a very longish GC_explicit getting called by system server process on behalf of postVideoEvent_l() function of media server process.This can be seen in the systrace i am attaching below. Also the logs have GC_EXPLICIT calls just before frame drops(cancel buffers). These GC calls are lasting for around 100-200 ms.

Any particular reason for these Explicit GC calls.

Attached is the location of the Systrace: https://www.dropbox.com/s/znxpgz9qhpjmc1e/mytrace5.html?dl=0

One example instance of the above can be seen from 9300ms to 9450ms. This duration is followed by a slew of cancel buffer calls.

Logcat too has following messages during above said interval:

```
D/dalvikvm( 2052): **GC_EXPLICIT** freed 31K, 11% free 6518K/7280K, paused **18ms+16ms, total 124ms**
E/AwesomePlayer(  813): we're late by 124714 us (0.12 secs) dropping one after 52 frames
E/AwesomePlayer(  813): getting release from here 22222
E/OMXCodec(  813): cancel Buffer to native window 
E/OMXCodec(  813): [OMX.hantro.G1.video.decoder] **Calling cancelBuffer** on buffer 0xb6ff927c
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What it basically means is that your memory is getting very low, and the `GC`=Garbage collector is being called to clear as much memory as possible so your video does not crash. However, the garbage collector is not always very fast, and it seems that your memory gets faster eaten than freed.

There are 2 solutions: More memory, or less memory consumption.

Comment: I understand that the garbage collection is happening. But AFAIK, EXPLICIT GC calls should not be made. Correct? I believe concurrent GC should be used. Sorry if i have wrong idea. I was a core kernel guy. Have recently made the jump to userspace and trying to make sense of things. :)

Comment: Yes you are right, normally it is best to do concurrent GCs, they are called Explicitly I think because the memory reaches a lower threshold. The concurrent call would be too slow in this case.